# Java 8 and file process 30 MB excel

Tags: java, excel, email

One of my task includes to use only `Java 8` and if required then only `Spring`, basically with minimal dependencies for this project.

There is one 30 MB size excel that could grow.  This comes up daily via FTP and need to process individual rows and then final report need to be emailed.

Now my problem is file is too big, please suggest best way to get it processed without any out of memory error.

thanks

Comment: Can you some more information? What have you tried (code)? What's the exception message, etc

Comment: What is the problem with the Excel file? What is your concrete problem?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of reading the lines of the file is in-memory – both Guava and Apache Commons IO provide a quick way to do just that:

> Files.readLines(new File(path), Charsets.UTF_8);
>
> FileUtils.readLines(new File(path));

The problem with this approach is that all the file lines are kept in memory – which will quickly lead to OutOfMemoryError if the File is large enough.

```
For example – reading a ~1Gb file:

@Test
public void givenUsingGuava_whenIteratingAFile_thenWorks() throws IOException {
    String path = ...
    Files.readLines(new File(path), Charsets.UTF_8);
}
```

This starts off with a small amount of memory being consumed: (~0 Mb consumed)

```
[main] INFO  org.baeldung.java.CoreJavaIoUnitTest - Total Memory: 128 Mb
[main] INFO  org.baeldung.java.CoreJavaIoUnitTest - Free Memory: 116 Mb
```

However, after the full file has been processed, we have at the end: (~2 Gb consumed)

```
[main] INFO  org.baeldung.java.CoreJavaIoUnitTest - Total Memory: 2666 Mb
[main] INFO  org.baeldung.java.CoreJavaIoUnitTest - Free Memory: 490 Mb
```

Which means that about 2.1 Gb of memory are consumed by the process – the reason is simple – the lines of the file are all being stored in memory now.

It should be obvious by this point that keeping in-memory the contents of the file will quickly exhaust the available memory – regardless of how much that actually is.

What’s more, we usually don’t need all of the lines in the file in memory at once – instead, we just need to be able to iterate through each one, do some processing and throw it away. So, this is exactly what we’re going to do – iterate through the lines without holding the in memory.

**Streaming with Apache Commons IO**

The same can be achieved using the Commons IO library as well, by using the custom LineIterator provided by the library:

```
LineIterator it = FileUtils.lineIterator(theFile, "UTF-8");
try {
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String line = it.nextLine();
        // do something with line
    }
} finally {
    LineIterator.closeQuietly(it);
}
```

> Since the entire file is not fully in memory – this will also result
>   in pretty conservative memory consumption numbers: (~150 Mb consumed)

```
[main] INFO  o.b.java.CoreJavaIoIntegrationTest - Total Memory: 752 Mb
[main] INFO  o.b.java.CoreJavaIoIntegrationTest - Free Memory: 564 Mb
```

Comment: Thanks I appreciate, Let me check on this and will +1 if it works :)

Comment: @NotAvail How using Guava or Apache Commons IO would match your requirement to stick with Java 8 or Spring?

Comment: How does your solution help processing large Excel files?

Comment: Maybe you can find equivalent with java.nio in Java8.

Comment: You are right.  Initially I am looking for java 8 solution.  I am still exploring option and keeping Apache commons as backup plan.  Still my assignment is under progress.  Any equivalent solution in Java 8 would be really appreciable.  Exploring nio as well.